# Python - Dicionário - Escrita e leitura correta

Tags: python, dicionário

Eu estou com um problema para ler os dados de um dicionário que criei para salvar dados reconstruídos por uma função...

O dicionário é escrito sempre que o valor de *Amp* e *t* é reconstruído, no loop col. A cada loop de row o dicionário é gravado em uma lista.

Trecho do código onde o dicionário é escrito:

```py
def OptimalFilter(inNoiseMatrix, inSi, inGsig, inDgSig):
    AmpTime = Verif = dict()
    ListData = []
    for row in range(0,1000):
        for col in range(0,9):
            ...
            ...
            Amp = mm(aCoef.T,Si)
            t   = mm(bCoef.T,Si)/mm(aCoef.T,Si)
            AmpTime.update({'E_Cell_'+str(col+1): Amp, 't_Cell_'+str(col+1): t})
        ListData.append(AmpTime) 
return ListData
```

Eu verifiquei a reconstrução imprimindo os valores de *Amp* e *t* e estão corretos. O problema ocorre quando vou processar os dados da lista que a função devolve. Ao escolher uma chave do dicionário e iterar nas listas o valor é igual:

```
AmpTimeXTvalid = OptimalFilter(Noise[3000:], XTvalid, gSig[3000:], DgSig[3000:])

for i in range(20):
    print(AmpTimeXTvalid[i]['E_Cell_1'])
9975.71782251447
9975.71782251447
9975.71782251447
9975.71782251447
9975.71782251447
9975.71782251447
9975.71782251447
9975.71782251447
9975.71782251447
9975.71782251447
9975.71782251447
9975.71782251447
9975.71782251447
9975.71782251447
```

O que eu fiz de errado na escrita/leitura do dicionário?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o problema esteja na linha abaixo:

```
AmpTime.update({'E_Cell_'+str(col+1): Amp, 't_Cell_'+str(col+1): t})
```

Você pode alterar para:

```
AmpTime['E_Cell_'+str(col+1)] = Amp
AmpTime['t_Cell_'+str(col+1)] = t
```

A leitura do mesmo será um pouco diferente do que você está fazendo. Mas, acredito que você não tenha problema com isso.

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão... depois de um tempo encontrei o erro. Está no fato de eu ter esquecido de limpar o dicionário antes de entrar no loop col. Após remover o local da linha `AmpTime = Verif = dict()` para antes de entrar no loop col funcionou corretamente.